# $f(z)$ is a polynomial $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a entire function such that $$\lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\infty$$

How to prove that $f(z)$ is a polynomial using  maximum modulus principle (without the use of Laurent series).

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Well tell me if I'm wrong, but : z--> exp(z) is an entire function, verifies lim f(z)= ∞, and is not a polynomial right?

Comment: Consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} e^{2n\pi i}=1$

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry

Comment: @felipeuni is that a correct counter example, perhaps the limit needs to be taken for $z\in\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ rather than $\Bbb N$

Comment: @ellya  By sequences $z_n\to \infty$ , $f(z_n)\to \infty$ , $z_n=2n\pi i$.

Comment: @felipeuni I mean for example $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi n)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$ is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(z)=\infty$ means that $\infty$ is a pole of $f$ (and not an essential singularity as would be the case for $f(z)=\exp z$).
Hence for suitable $k\in\mathbb N$, $g(z):=z^nf(1/z)$ is entire. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $k$ or $n$ ?...