# Show an entire function $f$ is a polynomal if $f(z)\to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to use the theorem any holomorphic function on Rieman sphere is a rational function, and hence a polynomial. So, I want to show that $f$ is holomorphic on Rieman sphere. So first thing I am trying to do is show that $\infty$ is a removable singularity, since if it is removeable $f$ can extend to a holomorphic function on Rieman sphere then I can apply the theorem I mentioned and I am done. But I am having trouble showing that.

Any hint and nudge toward right direction would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Get rid of the zeros (which are only finite in number) and apply Liouville to $\frac 1  f$. [The question is a duplicate].

Comment: @geetha290krm thatnks for the comment, when you say the set of zeros is finite, is it because of the following: Suppose $E$ is the set of zeros of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$ and assume to contrary that $E$ is not finite, then there exists accumulation point $x$ of sequence in $E$ and hence $x\in \mathbb{C}$. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is open and connected we must have $f$ is identically zero, which contradicts $f$ goes to infinity.?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Check these: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1079463/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/966392/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2924936/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3772707/42969.